# Harm in referencing unused assemblies in an asp.net application

Tags: asp.net, .net-assembly

If you reference assemblies that are not being used in the project, what are the drawbacks?

Comment: only on first compile that add more data on the memory to be able the compile done, even that is not that much, so minimum is the drawbacks

Comment: what are the advantages?

Comment: possibe duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4162714/whats-the-costs-of-unused-assembly-references